# Tricky order of evaluation in multiple assignment

Tags: python, variables, operator-precedence

I know the basic rule regarding the multiple assignment in Python:

- all expressions at the right part of the assignment are evaluated first
- then evaluated values are bound to variables at the left part

But actually I encountered something quite different and a little more complicated; I would like to know if I may rely on it. While debugging an algorithm, I suddenly discovered that a bug was related to the line:

```
k[s], k[p] = k[p], None
```

Because my algorithm found a case where `s` and `p` were equal. And obviously in that case, the final value is `k[s]=k[p]=None`.

In that very specific case, I would rather like the result of:

```
k[p], k[s] = None, k[p]
```

which behaves as I want in all cases, even when `p == s`. In that case, obviously, `k[p]` initially takes the value `None` and then the value `k[p]` back.

Of course I am aware that it could be a good idea to make one test more in order to have a more readable code, but I am very curious to know about the policy of the language in that lesser-known case: *what happens when the same variable is affected twice in a multiple assignment?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to rely on this.

From the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)

> If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from **left to right**, to the corresponding targets.

(emphasis mine)

```
k[s], k[s] = k[s], None
```

is equivalent to

```
t = k[s]
k[s] = t
k[s] = None
```

Side note: The evaluation order also holds when the right side is a dynamic iterable, e.g. a generator. All necessary elements will be extracted first and assigned left to right.

Comment: Of course, while you *can* rely on this, you *shouldn't*, as an explicitly sequential assignment makes the code much clearer when the order of assignment matters. I'd probably wrap the `k[p], k[s] = None, k[p]` in an `if p != s` for maximum clarity.

Comment: @user2357112 Or at least write a comment why the code works as expected also in the corner case. Still "[Djikstra would not have liked this](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra#1990s)".

Answer (score 1):

The python [docs](http://If%20the%20target%20list%20is%20a%20comma-separated%20list%20of%20targets:%20The%20object%20must%20be%20an%20iterable%20with%20the%20same%20number%20of%20items%20as%20there%20are%20targets%20in%20the%20target%20list,%20and%20the%20items%20are%20assigned,%20from%20left%20to%20right,%20to%20the%20corresponding%20targets.) gives the answer :

> If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, `from left to right`, to the corresponding targets.